# How to delay the outcoming data stream in Snap

Tags: haskell, streaming, haskell-snap-framework

I can send GET requests via a WiFi shield (ESP8266) on an Arduino Mega and I have a Snap-Webserver running, that serves a static directory with large .txt-Files (~ 1 MB).

Unfortunately, I can't parse the incoming data with an Arduino as fast as it gets send. I lose around ~ 50% of the incoming data.

Is there a possibility to configure Snap that it would delay the outcoming stream of data? It would be perfect if I could tell Snap to wait ~ 10 ms after a delimiter in the .txt-file ('\n' for example).

Comment: That sounds strange. In a standard setup the underlying transport layer for HTTP is TCP, which ensures reliable delivery. To quote [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transmission_Control_Protocol&oldid=674796728#Flow_control) _"TCP uses an end-to-end flow control protocol to avoid having the sender send data too fast for the TCP receiver to receive and process it reliably."_

Comment: I thought so too, but the only thing I see is the loss of data and I just can get behind why this comes up. Could it be that the driver for the WiFi shield doesn't implement TCP the way you described?

Comment: You could rewrite the Arduino code to make multiple GET calls with a `Range:` header.

Comment: @Cirquit Before trying to implement some throttling solution, I'd advise to try to get deeper in the source of the problem. In particular, to use a tool like [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) or [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) and observe what is happening, what the network traffic look like, if all data is delivered etc. Otherwise your workaround can just mask another issue that will come back to bite you later.

Comment: I found the error in my code. Unfortunately it opened up another problem where a possible solution would be to limit the fragement-size from the tcp. The problem lies in the Arduino Mega which has only 2KB Ram - but the fragments I get are almost always between 4KB. Even if I could sometimes save the incoming data, if i want to search or split it, the Arduino just stops everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would insert a proxy server to throttle the data.

Here is a simple proxy written in 100 lines of Python which would be easy to modify to add output delays:

http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-proxy-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/

Comment: I don't know any python, but I will try my best to get this running. Going to report / accept it as soon I get some results!

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't see any change, even when I manipulated delay / packetsize. I modified the `on_recv` so it would split the incoming data in chunks via my delimiter `*` and then while iterating the list I used `time.sleep(1)` after every send. It should've waited 1 second after every chunk, but it didn't :( http://lpaste.net/138291

Comment: Ok I got it! I added a custom delimiter so the "GET" request doesn't get splitted with my data. http://lpaste.net/138292